# How to properly update nested array while multithreading in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm learning how to program, and in my journey, I decided to learn how to use databases and the chosen one was mongodb. 
In my db, I have a object called WarClan, and inside WarClan, I have an List of ClanUser, and each ClanUser have a List of GameItem, which is supposed to be the player inventory. Like represented bellow:

```
public class WarClan
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string ClanName { get; set; }
    public List<ClanUser> ClanUsers { get; set; }
}
public class ClanUser
{
    public int Cid { get; set; }
    public List<GameItem> Inventario {get;set;}
}
```

I have a "GameServer" which has multiples channel instances running in different threads. And the player can be connected in multiples channels at once. The Game has some functions for example, item giveaway, item drops, inventory commands and etc. 
Yesterday I realized that a player sold an item on the market, but the item wasn't taken away. And now I believe its the way I wrote the code. Here is my code to "update inventory"(which update the whole player data, lol):

```
public async Task UpdateUser(WarClan clan, ClanUser user) 
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<WarClan>("clans");
        var arrayFilter = Builders<WarClan>.Filter.Eq("ClanName", clan.ClanName)
                & Builders<WarClan>.Filter.Eq("ClanUsers.Cid", user.Cid);
        var arrayUpdate = Builders<WarClan>.Update.Set("ClanUsers.$", user);
        await collection.UpdateOneAsync(arrayFilter, arrayUpdate);
    }
```

I believe that at same time the item was sold, he did something that needs to call update user too, and I think something like this happened(I'm not sure, just trying to understand):

```
    //Thread1:
    var user = await GetUser(123456); //By CID
    user.Inventario.Add(Item3);
    await UpdateUser(clan, user);

    //Thread2:
    var user = await GetUser(123456); //By CID
    user.Inventario.Add(Item4);
    await UpdateUser(clan, user);

/*
* The expected result: 
* User.Inventario = Item3, Item4
* 
* Given result:
* User.Inventario = Item4 
* OR
* User.Inventario = Item3
*/
```

How can I avoid problems like this? I'm a little bit lost at this point, I don't know what to search D:

Comment: Are you expecting multiple channels by multiple `var collection = db.GetCollection<WarClan>("clans");`? Or you have some setup for that? Can you post us which code is responsible for different threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just by not replacing a whole document when updating it. For inventory, since deleting by index was a pain for me, I created a ObjectId for every item in the inventory. So, when player buy it, I delete it by its UniqueId:

```
public async Task RemoveInventoryItemAsync(ObjectId userId, ObjectId itemId)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<ClanUser>("users");
        var arrayFilter = Builders<ClanUser>.Filter.Where(x => x._Id == userId);
        var arrayUpdate = Builders<ClanUser>.Update.PullFilter(x => x.Inventario, c => c.UniqueId == itemId);

        await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(arrayFilter, arrayUpdate);
    }
```

I did some millions tests, and looks pretty good for me! Also I created a dedicated table for users, "WarClan.ClanUsers" now contains only a array of ObjectId, which is the ObjectId of a player on the table "users". Don't know if its recommended tho.